# does mysqli_real_escape_string does Client-server round trip?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am re-writing the web application and would like to know whether `mysqli_real_escape_string` function does Client-server round trip ?

i am using it like this .

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link));
}

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

does mysqli_real_escape_string Client-server round trip?

so if i use mysqli_real_escape_string 4 times then will there 4 Client-server round trips ?

Answer (score 2):

According to this source code: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c

`mysqli_real_escape_string` calls `mysql_real_escape_string`.

PHP_FUNCTION(mysql_real_escape_string) is defined here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c

It calls `mysql_real_escape_string` from mysql library. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Sorry, I was unable to access launchpad.net mysql source code, but I looked in twitter mysql source code https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/libmysql/libmysql.c

And saw this:

```
ulong STDCALL
mysql_real_escape_string(MYSQL *mysql, char *to,const char *from,
ulong length)
{
   if (mysql->server_status & SERVER_STATUS_NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES)
      return (uint) escape_quotes_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length);
          return (uint) escape_string_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length);
}
```

`escape_quotes_for_mysql` and `escape_string_for_mysql` are defined in [charset.c](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/db7562e81d745021549a0e3b9c3d2386586c6bac/mysys/charset.c), and they don't send any info to remote MySQL server.

So, going all the way to the bottom, I can say: `mysqli_real_escape_string` does not do Client-server round trip.

Comment: above you said "they don't send any info to remote MySQL server" , whther they send to local mysql server ? it doesnt matter remote or local to me, just wanted to make sure whether it does round trip, i dont see the point of asking the connecttion name as first parameter if they are doing round trip .

Comment: @AMB The functions needs the connection parameter to obtain the current connection's encoding. Respecting the encoding is essential for proper escaping.